# ruby 1.8.7 & ruby 2 without rmv, failed instalation

Tags: ruby, rvm

I installed ruby 2.0  (from sources) in a centos that already had ruby 1.8.7.
I did not know that there was a previous installation.
I also noticed that had installed RVM. Now it doesn't work.

The RVM output

```
$ /usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm list
$ rvm rubies
 No rvm rubies installed yet. Try 'rvm help install'.
```

From what I understand, RVM does not know there is already a installed version of Ruby.

Is possible uninstall all versions and reinstall ruby with RVM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RVM allows "mounting" system rubies:

```
rvm mount /path/to/ruby
```

Or assuming all rubies are added to `PATH`

```
rvm automount
```

RVM will find any `ruby` binary available on `PATH` and will add it to `rvm list`

Comment: ok, rvm installed as user and found the 2 versions of ruby.
now only have to define which version is the one that needs to use my program.  http://pastie.org/8107465

Comment: I would suggest `rvm use ext-ruby-2.0.0-p0 --default`

Answer (score 0):

RVM does not care for rubies installed at the system level. It installs rubies to RVMs own folder inside of the users home directory. You should just install the desired ruby version using RVM. Since the RVM rubies should have precedence over the system-installed ruby, that should work out just fine.